# Saving a google chart via php

Tags: javascript, php, web, charts

I have `PHP` code that grabs some data from a server and then uses it to construct a PDF. As part of the PDF, I'd like to include a google chart. However, google chart is `Javascript`. Since I'm relatively new to web programming, can anyone provide suggestions on how I can incorporate google charts into a `PHP` script. Note, the data that the `PHP` script retrieves will be needed to construct the chart, so if it is a separate `Javascript` file or something, then it will need to somehow pass in data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i wouldn't use a google cart, i would use a chart built by something that provides an image, sit it can easily be embedded in a pdf

Comment: exactly, you need a charting system that generates an image not a bunch of javascript code that needs a browser to display it

Comment: stuff like html2canvas might be of use.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844629/php-google-charts-api). Essentially, you want the [Google Image Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) or you want to host the chart somewhere else and then use a PHP library to grab a screenshot and edit it (ImageMagick and GD are good places to start).

Comment: @beardedlinuxgeek but it's deprecated...

Comment: @CodeGuy but still supported until April 2015. If you're not going to need your program after that then use Google's API. Otherwise I said you need to host the chart and use something like [URL2PNG](https://www.url2png.com/) to take a screenshot and the manipulate it in PHP with ImageMagick or GD.

Answer (score 0):

The google chart is a javascript object.  You can send the object to your PHP script via AJAX.
Then json_decode(obj) in your php script, which will turn your javascript object into a PHP stdClass Object.  You can then incorporate the information from your script into the object, json_encode() back into a json object and echo the response back to your page to update the view.

Comment: and where is the image for the pdf?

Comment: @mstewart thanks for your answer however I guess I still don't understand how this would generate an image that I can use. Could you give a complete example?